# php_dbase.dll error when starting PHP 5.4

Tags: php, dll, wamp, dbase

I just updated my PHP to 5.4.16 in WAMP and i get the following error when I start the services with the `php_dbase.dll` extension enabled:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: dbase: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20090626
>   PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
>   These options need to match
>    in Unknown on line 0

Any ideas on how to fix this or get the correct DLL for this version?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your dbase module is compiled with MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)  and PHP is compiled with VC2010. I guess they are not as compatible as they hoped.

You will have to find a dbase module compiled with VC2010 for them to work together.
I had a lok and I cannot find one, so if you do please post a where to find it link here.